# Call toString when trying to print object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to mimic the behavior of Java to call the `toString()` method when we try to print the object using `console.log` statement or `alert`.

Currently, I have tried something like

```js
class Some {
    constructor(array = []) {
        this.pvtData = array;
    }

    toString = () => JSON.stringify(this.pvtData);
}

const s = new Some([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(s);
```

The expected output should be

```
[1,2,3]
```

But, I am getting the output as

```
{
  "toString": () => JSON.stringify(this.pvtData),
  "pvtData": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

Can anyone help me in resolving the issue and getting the desired output?

Note:
I don't want to use `console.log(s.toString());`. Basically, the `console.log` statement shouldn't change.

Comment: [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are not fitting well to be used as methods.

Comment: @Teemu - The above is fine (in an environment that supports the [class fields proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), which is most now. It'll close over the right `this`.

Comment: If you want to implicitly call `toString()`, use it in a scenario where it is *coerced* to be string like `alert(s)` or `console.log(s + '')`

Answer (score 7):

What you're doing will work for `alert` because `alert` converts its argument to string, but not for `console.log` with most consoles, because they don't convert to string, they try to show you a representation of the object.

There is no equivalent method for `console.log` across environments.¹ If you want that to happen for `console.log`, you'll have to override it:

```
const oldLog = console.log.bind(console);
console.log = (...args) => oldLog(...args.map(String));
```

Live Example:

```js
class Some {
    constructor(array = []) {
        this.pvtData = array;
    }

    toString = () => JSON.stringify(this.pvtData);
}

const oldLog = console.log.bind(console);
console.log = (...args) => oldLog(...args.map(String));
const s = new Some([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(s);
```

Obviously, don't do that in a general-purpose library that other people are going to use. It's fine in your own app or page, though.

Or better yet, just have your own logging function that you use instead that wraps `console.log`:

```js
// The log function
const log = (...args) => console.log(...args.map(String));

// Usage
class Some {
    constructor(array = []) {
        this.pvtData = array;
    }

    toString = () => JSON.stringify(this.pvtData);
}
const s = new Some([1, 2, 3]);
log(s);
```

---

¹ In Node.js, the console used to look for a method called `inspect`, but they stopped doing that a while back.

---

Side note: There's usually no reason to make `toString` an arrow function. It works (in an environment that supports the [class fields proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields)), but it's usually unnecessary. Just make it a method:

```
class Some {
    constructor(array = []) {
        this.pvtData = array;
    }

    toString() {
        return JSON.stringify(this.pvtData);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to create some utils which can be used across multiple applications, so can there be any generic method that I can use. That will be great.

Comment: @NikhilGoyal - I don't understand...?

Comment: I was thinking of creating a library only. As you mentioned, this approach will not suit for that.

Comment: @NikhilGoyal - I would have an internal `log` function just for your library code, and call that.